# MySQL IN condition gets results with always false condition

Tags: mysql

I need a condition that when used with an IN condition, it won't return any results. I initially thought this would work, but it still gives back results:

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE myColumn IN (SELECT FALSE FROM dual WHERE FALSE);
```

Is there a condition I could put in the IN condition to have it always return no results?

NOTE: This is being used in a PHP function where the column could be any type with any value.

Comment: How about an "id" you know can't be there, like 0?

Comment: I'm using this in a PHP function where the column could be virtually anything. I'll update my question to specify that.

Comment: If you want the query to return no results, why not just *not run it* in the first place?

Comment: Instead of selecting false, you could select a random GUID; the likelihood of that matching is almost 0...though I am not sure if MySQL would try to convert it to a number. ...Nevermind, just confirmed MySQL does convert the guid in the in to a number.

Comment: If you mean what I think you mean when you say _"a PHP function where the column could be virtually anything"_, I'd have to say that is a bad idea to start with.

Comment: I'm using it in a PHP function that generates unique parameter aliases for values when parameterizing for IN conditions. Everywhere this function is being used will already have a myColumn IN (<insert condition here>). If values are passed into the function, I want the parameterized values as the condition and if the values being passed in are an empty array I want it to return nothing. It makes the code cleaner that way. @RocketHazmat

Comment: Are trying to pass expressions as parameters to parameterized queries, or just as parameters to this php function?

Comment: @Sloganho: Wouldn't it be easier to skip running the SQL at all if you have an empty array?  That sounds cleaner to me than to try to run a query to specifically return nothing.

Comment: How is it a bad idea if I want to parameterize values for any column? Let's say it's an id column - I pass in an array of ids and it gives me a key-value array of parameter aliases for ids and their values. Let's say it's a column with a text value, I pass in an array of text and it gives me a key-value array of parameter aliases for the text values and their values. It's the same thing for int values or binary values etc. @Uueerdo

Comment: No because the condition could be in an ON condition in one of the joins or there might be other conditions I want to run in the query. And rather than change the code everywhere to run or not run the SQL I'd rather just change the code in one central location (in the function) @RocketHazmat

Comment: Can you give an actual table `MyTable` with actual data for which your query would return results?

Comment: I guess I'd have to see the function, I was imaging dynamic query construction based on users choosing the fields; but it sound more like you are trying to sort of extend parameterized querying.

Comment: Oh yeah, sorry about that. I thought about explaining the function and everything behind it but I figured it was irrelevant because I just wanted to know how to get no results @Uueerdo

Comment: @trincot I saw your comment saying to do SELECT NULL FROM dual WHERE NULL; and I've tested it on a bunch of different columns including columns that have NULL values and it seems to work great. If you want to make that an actual answer I'll accept it.

Comment: Yeah, probably not really that relevant, but in any case, I don't think there is a standard way to guarantee `field in (list)` is false.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of `false` use `null`. When `null` occurs in an expression, that always leads to a overall `null` value (there are some exceptions, like with `is null` but not in this context of `in`):

```
... in (select null from dual where null)
```

Comment: NULL is always a good one. It's not equal and it's not not equal which is why you need to explicitly test for it with is_null.